# Intersecting geodesics on a surface from non-intersecting geodesics

Tags: gn.general-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $a$ and $b$ be non-intersecting closed geodesics on a hyperbolic surface. Can these curves be homotopied to transversely intersect but still be geodesics?

Comment: No. The closed geodesic in a homotopy class is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The "geodesic parametrization" of a curve is unique (up to pre-composition with a rotation) in the curve's homotopy class. You can find more information in the book "A primer on mapping class groups".

Edit: and Lee beat me to the answer by just two minutes!  I'll leave this here for the reference.

Comment: Here's a link to _A primer on mapping class groups_ by Farb and Margolit: https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/farbmarg.pdf